# How do I draw this plot in polar coordinates?

Tags: geometry

This being a  polar plot

r = $ \frac{2}{2-cos\theta} $

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can always try to write the equation in cartesian coordinates.

$$2r-r\cos\theta=2$$
$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x=2$$
$$4x^2+4y^2=x^2+4x+4$$

This seems an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually asking how to plot it there is such a thing as polar graph paper. A web search for that will find some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ajotatxe's answer is a fine method of approaching the problem - some polar graphs are best approached by switching to cartestian and plotting. Note also that $-1\leq \cos \theta \leq 1$. So why not just try a few values of $\theta$ since as $\theta$ cycles, so does $r$. For example,
$$
r=\frac{2}{2-\cos \frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{2}{2-\cos \frac{9\pi}{4}}=\cdots
$$
It would only take a few unit circle $\theta$ values to see what the graph is - an ellipse:
[image]